# Intellij 11.1.1, Corona API code completion not working

Tags: lua, intellij-idea

## Problem

Installed

- IntelliJ 11.1.1,
- Lua for Windows (5.1),
- Corona SDK,
- Corona API from https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/idlua-sdk-corona

**Auto completion not working properly.**

It displays e.g. `physics`, but not e.g. `physics.addBody`, as shown in this screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having the same trouble. The only way I could get it to work is by splitting the API file into separate files and creating a module for each.

So you'd open up the corona_api.lua, and copy all of the physics functions into a new file called "physics" then inside this file you should do something like this;

```
module "physics"
function  addBody() end
function  getGravity() end
function  newJoint() end
function  pause() end
and so on...
```

you can find and replace the physics. at the start of the functions to make life easier.

Comment: Where do I put the physics.lua file? How do I enable its content for the autocomplete functionality?

Comment: put it in the same folder as your corona api file. It's the folder you see in your screenshot called sylvanaar2-idlua-sdk-corona.

as long as you have the module "physics" line above your functions when you type physics. in your other file it should bring up a list for you. When you add it make sure you close your project and reopen or it wont work.

Comment: In the end, I decided to use Cider IDE. However, I thank you anyway.